# PHP, echo one specific value from multiple associative arrays in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, echo, associative-array

I simply want to output the first name from each array. 
My comments in the code below explain. I do not want the keys, 
just the value. As you will see from what I describe below, 
I would love to have a loop that will produce the desired results. 
Is there a loop that will return the 'firstName' values only? 
Thanks....

---

```
<?php
$contacts = array(
    array(
        'firstName' => "Hoth",
        'lastName' => "Omiaenoed",
        'address'=> "76 S. Mammoth St.",
        'city' => "Westfield",
        'state' => "MA",
        'zip' => "01085",
    ),
    array(
        'firstName' => "Akae",
        'lastName' => "Uniaebul",
        'address'=> "8038 Shadow Brook Street",
        'city' => "Ocoee",
        'state' => "FL",
        'zip' => "34761",
    ),
    array(
        'firstName' => "Upae",
        'lastName' => "Aesuudoes",
        'address'=> "7044 N. School St.",
        'city' => "Riverdale",
        'state' => "GA",
        'zip' => "30274",
    ),
    array(
        'firstName' => "Doer",
        'lastName' => "Waezoeyo",
        'address'=> "338 Old Griffin St.",
        'city' => "Antioch",
        'state' => "TN",
        'zip' => "37013",
    ),
    array(
        'firstName' => "Ozae",
        'lastName' => "Iraeoewif",
        'address'=> "65 West Chapel Dr.",
        'city' => "San Angelo",
        'state' => "TX",
        'zip' => "76901",
    ),
    array(
        'firstName' => "Naes",
        'lastName' => "Ebaeaeraesh",
        'address'=> "34 Tower Street",
        'city' => "Huntersville",
        'state' => "NC",
        'zip' => "28078",
    )
);

/* I want to echo (print) just the first names from each array. I hoped I could use a "foreach" loop to do this and it seemed to me the one just below should work */

foreach ($contacts['firstName'] as $fname) {
    while (list( , $firstn) = each($fname)) {
        echo "$firstn <br/>";
    }
    echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
}

/* But it does not. Adding in ['firstName'] does not work. So, I have to use this one below, for lack of knowing what else to do. */

echo $contacts[0]['firstName']; echo "<br/>";
echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
echo $contacts[1]['firstName']; echo "<br/>";
echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
echo $contacts[2]['firstName']; echo "<br/>";
echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
echo $contacts[3]['firstName']; echo "<br/>";
echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
echo $contacts[4]['firstName']; echo "<br/>";
echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
echo $contacts[5]['firstName']; echo "<br/>";
echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";

/* I used this to output each complete array and it works just fine. */

foreach ($contacts as $info) {
    while (list( , $lines) = each ($info)) {
        echo "$lines <br/>";
    }
    echo "<hr/>";
}    

?>
```

Comment: its `foreach ($contacts as $values) { echo $values['firstName'] }` not `$contacts['firstName']`, think of it like: each sub array inside `$contacts` is `$values`, and the `firstName` is inside `$values`

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this with slight modification for appearances. 
 foreach ($contacts as $fnv) {
 echo $fnv['firstName'] ;
 echo "<br/>";
 echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
 }
    echo "<br/>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach ($contacts as $contact)
 { 
 echo $contact['firstName'];
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this with slight modification for appearances. 
 foreach ($contacts as $fnv) {
 echo $fnv['firstName'] ;
 echo "<br/>";
 echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
 }
    echo "<br/>";

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php   foreach ($contacts as $firtname) {
     echo $firtname['firstName'] ;   
    }
?>
```

I think this is what you are looking for ..

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this with slight modification for appearances. 
 foreach ($contacts as $fnv) {
 echo $fnv['firstName'] ;
 echo "<br/>";
 echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
 }
    echo "<br/>";

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array columns](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) if using php 5.5+

```
$list_fn = array_column($contacts, 'firstName');
```

Comment: @RobHeston if you combine this answer with `implode()` and apply your `<br>---<br>` as the glue, you can avoid the unnecessary trailing `<br>---<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what you can do.

```
$first_names = array_column($contacts, 'firstName'); // This returns what you need
foreach( $first_names as $name ){
    echo $name . "<br/>";
    echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
}
```

Hope this helped you!

Comment: Thank you very much! This also works. I had found that 
array_column and with it, as well as the other method, 
I never could see how to specify the first name value.
 $first_names = array_column($contacts, 'firstName');
 foreach( $first_names as $name ){
    echo $name . "<br/>";
    echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
 }
 echo "<br/>";

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($contacts as $contact){
    echo $contact['firstName']."</br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this with slight modification for appearances. 
 foreach ($contacts as $fnv) {
 echo $fnv['firstName'] ;
 echo "<br/>";
 echo "------------------------------------------<br/>";
 }
    echo "<br/>";